# Rails - How to give user notification messages on certain events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, alert

Im having a problem in rails. Im actually solving it but I guess theres a easier way out there.

I got user/membership/group models and user/invitation/event models. Membership joins user and group. Invitation joins user and event.

The membership and invitation model are equal. Group and event do have some equal some different columns. The membership/invitation model both have a boolean column "accepted", meaning the user which is invited to a group/event has to accept this invitation before he is a member/participant.

Now if a user signs in all group and event invitations should appear in a list. In fact I want to add more notifications to the system later on and events aren't even included in mine yet.

My solution is to add a notification model which belongs to user. So every user has many notifications. Additionally, this model is polymorphic and belongs to membership AND invitation.

```
#user model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
    has_many :invitations, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :events, :through => invitations
    has_many :notifications  

#membership model (equal to invitation model)
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
    has_one :notifications, :as => :noticeable

#group model (equal to event model but participants for members and invitation for membership)
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, :through => :memberships   
    has_many :members, :through => :memberships, :source => :user,
                :conditions => ['memberships.accepted = ?', true]

#notification model
class Notification  < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :noticeable, :polymorphic => true
```

Ive added some data to the database and Im testing it in the console

```
myUser = User.find(6) # will be exchanged with current_user in the actual program
```

I will run through all notifications with each do... but for the start I test all further actions on one notification

```
myNotice = myUser.notifications.first
```

so whether the noticeable_type of myNotices is membership or invitation I will render it as group or event notification
in this case noticeable_type=membership

```
myGroup = Group.find(Membership.find(myNotice.noticeable_id).group_id)
```

--> Do you want to join the Group "myGroup.name"? Yes | No

On Yes: `Membership.find(myNotice.noticeable_id).accepted = true`

On No: `Membership.find(myNotice.noticeable_id).destroy`

And: `myNotice.destroy`

Thats the my idea.
Is this the way to solve the problem?

The "each do" which goes through all notifications will be in a view file. Which means "Group.find(Membership.find(myNotice.noticeable_id).group_id)" has to be in the view file or a partial aswell. Isn't that a bit ugly?

I think Ive used a lot of "find" which means many SQL queries. Isn't there a way to reduce them with any "Ruby on Rails"-magic?

Thank you :)

Comment: you can try use .includes or .joins to join with your associate models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found how to solve this! I bumped into this problem again and googled "reverse polymorphic". I found the following post:
https://gist.github.com/runemadsen/1242485

> **Polymorphic Associations reversed.**
>   It's pretty easy to do polymorphic associations in Rails: A Picture
>   can belong to either a BlogPost or an Article. But what if you need
>   the relationship the other way around? A Picture, a Text and a Video
>   can belong to an Article, and that article can find all media by
>   calling @article.media
>   This example shows how to create an ArticleElement join model that handles the polymorphic relationship. To add fields that are common to all polymorphic models, add fields to the join model.

```
       class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
          has_many :article_elements
          has_many :pictures, :through => :article_elements, :source => :element, :source_type => 'Picture'
          has_many :videos, :through => :article_elements, :source => :element, :source_type => 'Video'
        end

        class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
          has_one :article_element, :as =>:element
          has_one :article, :through => :article_elements
        end

        class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
          has_one :article_element, :as =>:element
          has_one :article, :through => :article_elements 
        end

        class ArticleElement < ActiveRecord::Base
          belongs_to :article
          belongs_to :element, :polymorphic => true
        end

        t = Article.new
        t.article_elements  # []
        p = Picture.new
        t.article_elements.create(:element => p)
        t.article_elements  # [<ArticleElement id: 1, article_id: 1, element_id: 1, element_type: "Picture", created_at: "2011-09-26 18:26:45", updated_at: "2011-09-26 18:26:45">]
        t.pictures # [#<Picture id: 1, created_at: "2011-09-26 18:26:45", updated_at: "2011-09-26 18:26:45">]
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed something similar for my app, so updating the answer here in case someone finds it useful.

```
  #user model

   has_many :membership_notices, :through => :notifications, :source => :membership,  :conditions => {"notifications.noticeable_type" => "membership"}

   has_many :event_notices, :through => :notifications, :source => :event ,:conditions => {"notifications.noticeable_type" => "event"}
```

The notifications are now accessible as

```
  user.membership_notices
  user.event_notices
```

Comment: okay, but it isn't possible to access all notifications at once. like user.notices? Because that is what I actually need